# ensure 2 arguments are passed in a bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do i ensure 2 arguments are passed in a bat file?

I would like to echo a description of the arguments and exit the bat if there are not exactly 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Note 1 on [this](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/if.php) page about the need for a dummy when testing for empty strings.

```
IF dummy-==dummy-%1 (
    ECHO Syntax is blah blah
    EXIT /B
)

IF dummy-==dummy-%2 (
    ECHO Syntax is blah blah
    EXIT /B
)
```

Also I find [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) is a good reference when writing batch files.

Comment: Per @Daniel's answer, I reckon the first check is redundant.

Comment: I wrote 
IF dummy-==dummy-%2 (
    ECHO Blah
    EXIT /B
)

IF NOT dummy-==dummy-%3 (
    ECHO To many arguments
    EXIT /B
)

Comment: That `dummy-` syntax is ugly and adds no value.  CMD.EXE will compare the strings on either side of `==` character for character (after stripping leading and trailing whitespace), so you might as well say `if FOOBAR==FOO%1BAR` since it means the same thing.  But my preference is to use quote characters since it's much more legible.

Comment: @Daniel, I agree your syntax looks better, but the quotes serve essentially the same purpose; that is, they add no semantic value but adjust for a syntactic consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
if "%2"=="" goto :usage
```

and then put your usage text at the bottom, after a `:usage` label.  Just make sure you exit your script with `goto :eof` so you don't get the usage upon normal completion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using the `for` command:

```
@echo off

set /a argCount=0
for %%A in (%*) do set /a argCount+=1

@echo Number of args is: %argCount%

if %argCount% NEQ 2 (
    @echo Usage
    exit /b
)
```

This style will handle cases where you need to ensure you have more than 9 arguments.